# About program running independent from command line under unix

Tags: java, unix

I am writing a java program that runs under unix.
It would like run forever. But when I start it from command line, I have to leave that window open always until the program stop.
Could anyone give me some idea about how can i run it at back end? Just start it from command line then I could close that command line.
Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't want to "daemonize" it you can just use [nohup](http://compute.cnr.berkeley.edu/cgi-bin/man-cgi?nohup%201):

```
 $ nohup your-program &
 $ exit
```

and your-program will continue to run in the background until it finishes.

Answer (score 1):

You're asking about making your program a "daemon".  Check out [these](http://barelyenough.org/blog/2005/03/java-daemon/) [links](http://www.source-code.biz/snippets/java/7.htm) about daemonizing java programs, and [this one](http://www.mynitor.com/2010/02/28/daemonize-any-process-in-linux/) about daemonizing any process in linux.

Comment: Probably overkill -- the deleted answer of just running it in the background with `&` (or whatever your system/shell uses) is probably better.

Comment: That normally doesn't allow you to exit the command line like the OP is asking for.  On my machine, running `sleep 100 &` and then exiting the shell kills the sleep job.

Answer (score 1):

...Another option is to use the "screen" utility.   Its a little tricky if you've never used it,  but you can do things like launch a job in a terminal at work and easily reconnect to the same terminal from anywhere else to check on the status of the job.   I use it for connecting to servers where I run long-running jobs.   Without using screen my process would die if my local machine crashes, or the power goes out, or fire, etc.

Comment: +1 for screen. I used it for a similar thing sometime ago and its better than nohup for long running jobs.